# Defining weak relationship in Entity relationship model

Tags: inheritance, relationship, data-modeling, erd, entity-relationship

While creating Entity relationship model, I came up with a confusion:

here is an example of two entities:

> company (comp_id(pk), comp_name)
>
> topCompanies (rank(pk), comp_id(fk)) *contains a list of top ten or
>   hundred companies

it's not a specialization example as entity topCompanies can't exist on its own, it just contains all comp_id(s) which are in say top ten or hundred. so it means that topCompanies is a weak entity as it can't exist on its own. Now can they have an 'is a' relationship or 'is a' relationship is only limited to inheritance/specialization examples? If no then how should I describe their relationship?

**Also, is there any conventions while reading ERD? left-to-right / right-to-left?**

Comment: I don't understand your question about conventional direction on ER diagrams. Text on the diagram is read in the conventional direction of the language it's written in, but the diagram itself has no order-dependent elements. I suggest you study ER more carefully. Note that there's no such thing as a weak relationship as you mentioned in the title of your question - weak entities have identifying relationships.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's get the terminology straight. Entities and tables aren't the same thing. Tables (physical model) represent relations (logical model) which in ER (conceptual model) is separated into entity relations and relationship relations, which record facts about entity sets and relationship sets, respectively.

The `company` entity set is represented by the column `comp_id` in both tables. The `company` relation/table associates the `company` entity set (via its identifier/key) with a value set of names. The `topCompanies` relation/table associates the `company` entity set (via its identifier/key) with a `rank`.

Is the `rank` an entity set or a value set? ER generally demands that any set that determines a relation be an entity set, so let's say there's an entity set called `ranking`, identified and represented by the `rank` column. This `ranking` entity set has a relationship with the `company` entity set, which is what we see in the `topCompanies` table.

Thus, `topCompanies` is neither a weak entity nor a subtype of `company`. A weak entity set is identified by its parent entity set's key together with a local distinguishing attribute. A subtype entity set is identified by the same key as the supertype. However, the `topCompanies` relation/table doesn't depend on the `comp_id` at all. Rather, `comp_id` depends on the `rank`.

Here's an entity-relationship diagram that depicts it:

[image: top companies ER diagram]

Answer (score 0):

**topCompany is a subset of Company**. You got the relationship right. 
topCompany is a Company

so a topCompany has a foreign key that points to a Company. It's not weak since it has a primary key (the rank).

Comment: If you took away "Company" from your model, then topCompany has no meaning except being list of integers, hence you Company.

Comment: in that sense is weak.  But weak in ERD terms means an entity that does not have a primary key.  topCompany does have that. so it's not weak